# I am trying to fetch api from meal db website, it says the error failed to fetch API in the console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

Please find my recipeslice.js code. I am making recipe website using react-redux technology. I am facing issue in fetching api from the website of `"https://www.themealdb.com/api.php"`

```js
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios';

export const fetchRecipes = createAsyncThunk(
  'recipes/fetchRecipes',
  async () => {
    fetch('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
);

const recipesSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'recipes',
  initialState: {
    recipes: [],
    status: 'idle',
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchRecipes.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(fetchRecipes.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'succeeded';
        state.recipes = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(fetchRecipes.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.error = action.error.message;
      });
  },
});

export default recipesSlice.reducer;
```

Please help me to fetch api data from `"https://www.themealdb.com/api.php"` as I am making recipe website in react-redux technology.

I tried to add code in `recipeslice.js` file but the error in console is failed to fetch data.

I tried to add code in `recipeslice.js` file but the error in console is failed to fetch data and some more errors are this: `bundle.js:327     GET https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES`.

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The endpoint `"https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list"` returns the following JSON data response<sup>*</sup>:

```json
{
  "meals": [
    {
      "strCategory": "Beef"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Breakfast"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Chicken"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Dessert"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Goat"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Lamb"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Miscellaneous"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Pasta"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Pork"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Seafood"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Side"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Starter"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Vegan"
    },
    {
      "strCategory": "Vegetarian"
    }
  ]
}
```

*<sup>*</sup>I have no idea if this data is correct. I can only verify/validate it is the data that was requested.*

The issue I see with your `fetchRecipes` thunk is that it doesn't return anything.

```
export const fetchRecipes = createAsyncThunk(
  'recipes/fetchRecipes',
  async () => {
    // This fetch Promise isn't returned
    fetch('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list')
      .then(response => response.json())
      // console.log returns undefined
      .then(data => console.log(data))
      .catch(error => console.error(error));
  }
);
```

## Suggested Solution

- Return a value from the Thunk.
- Don't mix `async/await` with Promise chains, use one or the other.
- Don't forget to also return any thrown (*and caught*) errors for the `fetchRecipes.rejected` case. See [Handling Thunk Errors](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors) for more details.

### Using Promise chain

```
export const fetchRecipes = createAsyncThunk(
  'recipes/fetchRecipes',
  (_, thunkAPI) => {
    // Return Promise
    return fetch('https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        // log independently
        console.log(data);

        // return data from Promise chain
        return data;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
      );
  }
);
```

### Using `async/await`/`try/catch`

```
export const fetchRecipes = createAsyncThunk(
  'recipes/fetchRecipes',
  async (_, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'https://www.themealdb.com/api/json/v1/1/list.php?c=list'
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log(data);
      return data;
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
    }
  }
);
```